# LWC: how to clear previous selection from lightning-combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I have a data entry form using `lighting-input` and `lightning-combobox`.  When the user submits the form, I want to clear all fields so the user can make a new entry.

I'm using querySelectorAll and looping through each input and combobox element to set `value` to blank.  The input fields are cleared successfully, but the combobox fields are not cleared and the entries from the previous submission are still there.

How do I clear the combobox fields?  I've tried various combinations of `each.value` and `each.setValue()` but nothing works.

Here's the relevant html:

```
<template>
    <template if:false={isComplete}>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <lightning-input data-formfield="firstName" label="First Name" required></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <lightning-input data-formfield="lastName" label="Last Name" required></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <lightning-input data-formfield="zip" label="Zip Code" class="spec-req"></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <lightning-input data-formfield="mobile" label="Mobile" type="phone" class="spec-req"></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <lightning-input data-formfield="email" label="Email" type="email" class="spec-req"></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <lightning-input data-formfield="orgAffiliation" label="Org Affiliation"></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <lightning-input data-formfield="youth" label="Number of Youth" type="number"></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <template if:true={veteranStatusOptions.data}>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                    <lightning-combobox data-formfield="veteranStatus" label="Veteran Status" value={veteranStatus} options={veteranStatusOptions.data.values} onchange={handleStatusChange} placeholder="-select-" required></lightning-combobox>
                </div>
            </template>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <lightning-combobox data-formfield="waiver" label="Agree to Waive" value={waiver} options={yesnoOptions} onchange={handleWaiverChange} placeholder="-select-" required></lightning-combobox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

</template>
```

Here's the relevant JS:

```
// Clear variables and form for the next entry.
handleContinueEntry() {
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(each => {
        each.value = '';
    });
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox').forEach(each => {
        each.value = null;
    });
}
```

Here's the screenshot after clearing the fields:

[image: eb]

Comment: The only way I've been able to accomplish that is by having an option with the value of ''. I haven't come across a way that resets it to the default 'blank' value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see from your code, You Combobox are binded to two JS variables

`{veteranStatus}` and `{waiver}`

You have to make them as Null as well

```
this.veteranStatus = null;
this.waiver = null;
```

Comment: Of course!  How foolish of me to have missed all the variable bindings.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly set the `value` attribute of the `combobox`, there is no function in JS like `setValue()`.

```
this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox').forEach(each => {
    each.value = undefined;
});
```

Even setting `null` or `''` does work to.

See the live example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/m89rGQJIq/1/edit).

Comment: I tried `each.value = undefined`, `each.value = null`, and `each.value = ''`.  None of them work.

Comment: @DavidCheng I have updated my asnwer please check this work completely fine [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/m89rGQJIq/1/edit). There might be some other reason for this to fail in your case. If you are facing any error please update that in question